# is app indexing is necessary for instant app to show in google search

Tags: android, deep-linking, applinks, android-instant-apps, android-app-indexing

I have developed an instant app & published it into the play store, also has a website associated with the Instant App. tested the app link with the testing tool  [from here](https://developers.google.com/digital-asset-links/tools/generator).

The app is opened after clicking the link from other apps (gmail, hangouts), But clicking on my website from a google search is opening as a webpage instead of instant apps. Is there anything I have to do in order to redirect a web page to the app from google search.

I had published my instant app in play store. when i click the link from gmail it opens as instant app in some devices (Samsung s6 note ,moto g4 plus)

On some devices its not opening as instant app but buzzfeed.com/tasty opens as instant app. (one plus 3 & one plus 5).

my digital asset link is https://abdcoop.mybuzztm.com/.well-known/assetlinks.json

Anyone able to suggest what i am missing?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It is not necessary to use the App Indexing API. As long as you set up App Links, that's enough. Unfortunately, it can take several weeks for the change to show up in Google search results. We do consider that a problem and are working on a way to speed it up.

Comment: thanks for the reply.i have another doubt ,is the instant app settings are enabled by default ? or for the first time a user trying to install an instant app the permission settings page is to shown in order to enabled the option ? or the user has to manually go to settings->google settings -> instant app settings to enable the permission ?.

Comment: Most users now opt in via the recently updated Play Store Terms of Service, which now includes Instant Apps. If, for some reason, they haven't seen the new ToS, they will be promoted to opt in on first visiting and instant app. There is no need to opt in via settings unless the user previously opted out explicitly. I know the explicit opt-in step is popular in how-to videos, but it's unnecessary. I'm glad you asked!

Comment: @philio As previously discussed i had published my app in play store. when i click the link from gmail it opens as instant app in some devices (Samsung s6,moto g4 plus) , on some devices its not opening  as instant app but buzzfeed.com/tasty opens as instant app. (one plus series phones) .can you provide any details ?

Comment: this  is my assetlinks.json location url https://abdcoop.mybuzztm.com/.well-known/assetlinks.json

Comment: @DineshKannan I understand what you're saying, but I'm not sure what the issue could be, and I'm not able to debug atm. For now, I'd recommend breaking it out into a separate SO question to get better visibility.

Comment: can you provide me any resources which will work with instant apps ?. because some devices has instant app settings in the google settings and it opening links in browser .

Comment: @DineshKannan, I can explain why you had a device that could open Buzzfeed but not your app. That was caused by a delay in syncing the published state of your app to the device. It can take up to 24h for devices to resolve newly published instant apps. I tested your app on my Pixel XL that day and did not get the instant app, but today I do. I'm assuming this particular issue also resolved itself on your OnePlus, since your new SO question, https://stackoverflow.com/q/46312382/407058, doesn't mention it. (Your new question is perfectly valid in its own right.)

Comment: thanks for your reply. yeah its opening correctly in my one plus device also.still in mi 4 note, Le eco, sony both buzzfeed & my app is not working. but these devices has instant apps option in their settings..