# Link is not opened as instant app in some devices

Tags: android, deep-linking, applinks, android-instant-apps, digital-assets-links

I had published my instant app in play store. when i click the link from gmail it opens as instant app in some devices (Samsung s6 note ,moto g4 plus)

In some devices its not working ,but those devices has Settings->Google->Instant Apps option. but the instant app is not working.

my digital asset link is https://abdcoop.mybuzztm.com/.well-known/assetlinks.json

Anyone able to suggest what i am missing?

I have added my log.

```
I/Timeline: Timeline: Activity_launch_request time:74970969
I/ActivityManager: START u0 {act=android.intent.action.VIEW dat=https://www.google.com/... pkg=com.android.chrome cmp=com.android.chrome/com.google.android.apps.chrome.Main (has extras)} from uid 10087 on display 0
D/WtProcessController: onAMCreateActivity callback
D/ActivityTrigger: ActivityTrigger activityPauseTrigger 
E/ANDR-PERF-MPCTL: Invalid profile no. 0, total profiles 0 only
E/ActivityManager: Invalid thumbnail dimensions: 0x0
D/PowerManagerService: acquireWakeLockInternal: lock=176192276, flags=0x1, tag="*launch*", ws=WorkSource{10059}, uid=1000, pid=1562
D/PowerManagerService: updateWakeLockSummaryLocked: mWakefulness=Awake, mWakeLockSummary=0x1
D/PowerManagerService: updateUserActivitySummaryLocked: mWakefulness=Awake, mUserActivitySummary=0x1, nextTimeout=2222436507 (in 2147465528 ms)
D/WtProcessController: onAMPauseActivity callback
I/art: Note: end time exceeds epoch: 
I/art: Note: end time exceeds epoch: 
D/WtProcessController: onAMRestartActivity callback
D/WtProcessController: set foreground process size 2 pid:10443pacakgeName:com.android.chrome
I/Timeline: Timeline: App_transition_ready time:74971012
D/ConnectivityService: listenForNetwork for Listen from uid/pid:10059/10443 for NetworkRequest [ id=49, legacyType=-1, [ Capabilities: INTERNET&NOT_RESTRICTED&TRUSTED] ]
I/cr_InstantAppsHandler: Not handling with Instant Apps
I/Timeline: Timeline: Activity_launch_request time:74971029
D/Babel: onCreate: Shutdown runnable posted in onCreate with a delay of 5000 ms.
W/AD-PLUGIN-AppInstallActivateManager: Two apps are same
I/ActivityManager: START u0 {act=android.intent.action.VIEW dat=https://www.google.com/... flg=0x800000 pkg=com.android.chrome cmp=com.android.chrome/org.chromium.chrome.browser.customtabs.CustomTabActivity (has extras)} from uid 10059 on display 0
I/Timeline: Timeline: App_transition_ready time:74971039
D/WtProcessController: onAMCreateActivity callback
D/ActivityTrigger: ActivityTrigger activityPauseTrigger 
D/PowerManagerService: acquireWakeLockInternal: lock=176192276, flags=0x1, tag="*launch*", ws=WorkSource{10059}, uid=1000, pid=1562
D/PowerManagerService: updateWakeLockSummaryLocked: mWakefulness=Awake, mWakeLockSummary=0x1
D/PowerManagerService: updateUserActivitySummaryLocked: mWakefulness=Awake, mUserActivitySummary=0x1, nextTimeout=2222436507 (in 2147465465 ms)
D/DisplayPowerController: requestPowerState: policy=BRIGHT, useProximitySensor=false, screenBrightness=102, screenAutoBrightnessAdjustment=0.96850395, brightnessSetByUser=true, useAutoBrightness=true, blockScreenOn=false, lowPowerMode=false, boostScreenBrightness=false, dozeScreenBrightness=-1, dozeScreenState=UNKNOWN, waitForNegativeProximity=false
D/PowerManagerService: updateDisplayPowerStateLocked: mDisplayReady=true, policy=3, mWakefulness=1, mWakeLockSummary=0x1, mUserActivitySummary=0x1, mBootCompleted=true, mScreenBrightnessBoostInProgress=false
D/WtProcessController: onAMPauseActivity callback
D/Babel: Idle: Shutdown runnable posted in release with a delay of 5000 ms.
D/ActivityThreadInjector: clearCachedDrawables.
D/wpa_supplicant: wlan0: Control interface command 'SIGNAL_POLL'
D/wpa_supplicant: CTRL-DEBUG: global_ctrl_sock-sendto: sock=11 sndbuf=229376 outq=0 send_len=48
D/WtProcessController: onAMRestartActivity callback
I/Timeline: Timeline: App_transition_ready time:74971054
D/WtProcessController: onAMDestroyActivity callback
D/PowerManagerService: releaseWakeLockInternal: lock=16046967 [hangouts_rtcs], flags=0x0
D/PowerManagerNotifier: onWakeLockReleased: flags=1, tag="hangouts_rtcs", packageName=com.google.android.talk, ownerUid=10087, ownerPid=10590, workSource=null
D/PowerManagerService: updateWakeLockSummaryLocked: mWakefulness=Awake, mWakeLockSummary=0x1
D/PowerManagerService: updateUserActivitySummaryLocked: mWakefulness=Awake, mUserActivitySummary=0x1, nextTimeout=2222436507 (in 2147465446 ms)
D/DisplayPowerController: requestPowerState: policy=BRIGHT, useProximitySensor=false, screenBrightness=102, screenAutoBrightnessAdjustment=0.96850395, brightnessSetByUser=true, useAutoBrightness=true, blockScreenOn=false, lowPowerMode=false, boostScreenBrightness=false, dozeScreenBrightness=-1, dozeScreenState=UNKNOWN, waitForNegativeProximity=false
D/PowerManagerService: updateDisplayPowerStateLocked: mDisplayReady=true, policy=3, mWakefulness=1, mWakeLockSummary=0x1, mUserActivitySummary=0x1, mBootCompleted=true, mScreenBrightnessBoostInProgress=false
D/Babel: Idle: Shutdown runnable posted in release with a delay of 5000 ms.
I/Babel_Conv: Conversation loader finished for Ugxb1fhtNlDEfBW1SlN4AaABAagBiKycDw, count# 1
V/BoostFramework: BoostFramework() : mPerf = com.qualcomm.qti.Performance@5d28c18
V/BoostFramework: BoostFramework() : mPerf = com.qualcomm.qti.Performance@3e52671
I/ActivityManager: Start proc 12361:com.android.chrome:sandboxed_process3/u0i10 for service com.android.chrome/org.chromium.content.app.SandboxedProcessService3
I/art: Late-enabling -Xcheck:jni
D/WtProcessController: onAMProcStart callback
W/cr_tabmodel: Starting to fetch tab list.
E/cr_tabmodel: State file does not exist.
W/Binder_8: type=1400 audit(0.0:477087): avc: denied { ioctl } for path="socket:[978012]" dev="sockfs" ino=978012 ioctlcmd=7704 scontext=u:r:system_server:s0 tcontext=u:r:system_server:s0 tclass=unix_stream_socket permissive=0
D/ActivityThreadInjector: clearCachedDrawables.
W/Binder_8: type=1400 audit(0.0:477088): avc: denied { ioctl } for path="socket:[978012]" dev="sockfs" ino=978012 ioctlcmd=7704 scontext=u:r:system_server:s0 tcontext=u:r:system_server:s0 tclass=unix_stream_socket permissive=0
I/Timeline: Timeline: App_transition_ready time:74971116
D/TidaProvider: TidaProvider()
I/art: Background partial concurrent mark sweep GC freed 10565(740KB) AllocSpace objects, 1(1600KB) LOS objects, 30% free, 36MB/52MB, paused 3.391ms total 139.710ms
I/Timeline: Timeline: App_transition_ready time:74971143
I/Timeline: Timeline: App_transition_ready time:74971145
W/System: ClassLoader referenced unknown path: /system/app/Chrome/lib/arm
I/Timeline: Timeline: App_transition_ready time:74971151
I/Timeline: Timeline: App_transition_ready time:74971154
W/dboxed_process3: type=1400 audit(0.0:477089): avc: denied { search } for name="tmp" dev="dm-1" ino=21 scontext=u:r:isolated_app:s0:c512,c768 tcontext=u:object_r:shell_data_file:s0 tclass=dir permissive=0
I/Timeline: Timeline: App_transition_ready time:74971166
I/cr_ChildProcessService: Creating new ChildProcessService pid=12361
I/ActivityManager: Displayed com.android.chrome/org.chromium.chrome.browser.customtabs.CustomTabActivity: +116ms (total +162ms)
V/PhoneStatusBarPolicy: updateManagedProfile mManagedProfileFocused: false mKeyguardVisible: false mCurrentUserId:0 mCurrentProfileId:0 mSecondSpaceStatusIconVisible: true showIcon:false
```

Comment: Please attach the logcat messages that happen when you try to open the instant app from said devices.

Comment: @keyboardsurfer are you asking for the devices which works for instant apps ? or the not working devices ?

Comment: The one's that don't launch your instant app.

Comment: @keyboardsurfer i don't have the device with me rit now.. i have to go home and i will update the log.

Comment: Have you tried disabling and re-enabling Instant Apps from settings and then trying again?

Comment: @keyboardsurfer I have added my log

Comment: @keyboardsurfer i have updated my question.my app is working on the device on which buzzfeed.com/tasty works.but in some other devices its not working ( instant apps option is there & its running on 6 and higher)

Comment: `I/cr_InstantAppsHandler: Not handling with Instant Apps`
Is the line which states that it's not going to be handled. I don't see any valid URLs in the log though. Which one are you trying to launch?

Comment: @keyboardsurfer my instant app url is https://abdcoop.mybuzztm.com/pub/abudhabicoop. but in log i am not able to find the link.the link is there after chrome invoked.18195-18195/? I/chromium: [INFO:CONSOLE(1010)] "service worker register ", source: https://abdcoop.mybuzztm.com/pub/abudhabicoop (1010)

Comment: @keyboardsurfer  as per your previous post. if the link is not handled by  android means, can you provide any details about what are all the devices it supports.but the device has Settings->google-> instant app option enabled

Comment: If Instant Apps is enabled within settings, the device supports Android Instant Apps.

Comment: @keyboardsurfer can you provide me an link which will work to make sure it's working or not ?

Comment: @keyboardsurfer redmi note 4 which running in android 6.0.1 the instant app settings is enabled , in this phone https://www.buzzfeed.com/tasty link is opening in browser. instant app is not working.

Comment: One reason not to load the Instant App can be that the network is too slow to respond.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/154998/discussion-between-dinesh-kannan-and-keyboardsurfer).

Comment: @keyboardsurfer I had connected my mobile phone with the wifi only.. i have tried this multiple times still it opens as a url .. i ll share the device details,network speed. in the same network itself i tested in other device moto g4 plus. its working

Comment: Did you fix this yet? Have you tried launching your IA from other apps like Google Docs/Hangouts?

Comment: Also, sometimes stale cache can be a problem. Clear the data for Play Store, Play Services, and Chrome.

Answer (score 3):

From the documentation it shows:

> Android Instant Apps supports the latest Android devices from Android 6.0 (API level 23) through Android O, across more than 40 countries. We'll be rolling out to more devices and countries soon, including expanding support to Android 5.0 (API level 21) devices shortly.

So make sure your country is supported and the device contains Android Version 6 or more.(You can check this in the device). And if the device is Lollipop (Android 5.0). The functionality may have not been added yet, Though the Phone shows the Setting. So visit and stay in Touch with Android sources to check if the support feature has already been added to Lollipop devices yet!